# Find an element in a div using the attribute ends selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find  hidden element in a div using the attribute ends with selector and I am running into issues.

I have a jQuery object which represents div and I know that my hidden input is in this div and it ends with "-id", but I am not able to locate it.

This is my code

```
var clickedContainer = $(theThis).parent().parent().parent();
var id = clickedContainer.find([id$='-id']).val();
```

I get an error on the second line.

I guess, I don't know how to find an element in a div which is represented by a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to quote your argument to `find()`:

```
var id = clickedContainer.find("[id$='-id']").val();
```

(Just a note: when you say you "get an error", it's usually a good thing to actually say what the error message is.)